# applying a filter to a select box using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a webpage which has two `<select>` boxes: `Hadoop Distribution` and `Hadoop Version`.
I also have a map between the `Distribution` and the `Version`:

```
function hadoop_map() {
      var hash = Object();
      // replace this part of the code by a jQuery post 
      hash['Cloudera'] = ['4', '5'];
      hash['Apache'] = ['2.4', '2.3.0', '2.2.0', '2.1.1', '2.1.0', '2.0.6', '1.2.1'];
      hash['Hortonworks'] = ['2.1', '2.0', '1.3'];
      hash['Pivotal'] = [];
      hash['MapR'] = [];

      return hash;
   }
```

so, one select is:

```
<select id="hadoop_dist">
    <option>Cloudera</option>
    <option>Hortonworks</option>
    <option>Apache</option>
    <option>MapR</option
    <option>Pivotal</option>
</select>
```

while the other is

```
<select id="hadoop_version">
   <option>4</option>
   <option>5</option>
   <option>2.3.0</option>
    ...
 </select>
```

So, when I select `Cloudera` in the top box, I would like to only display the entries listed in the `hadoop_map` (i.e `4` and `5`) in the `hadoop_version` ?
How can I accomplish that using `jQuery`?

Answer (score 1):

Because of the nature of your data, one way convenient way is to construct it every time it changes. A little inefficient but a lot more readable and easily extendible than alternative options:

```
var hadoopMap = hadoop_map();

$('#hadoop_dist').change(function() {
    var selectedOption = $(this).val();
    var $options = $.map(hadoopMap[selectedOption], function(value) {
        return $('<option>').html(value);
    });

    $('#hadoop_version').empty().append($options);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

By using

```
.find('option').remove()
```

and then looping through the array for the chosen has property and using

```
.append('<option>' + item + '</option').
```

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y698egxe/1/) for a working example